# Catch an exception when user enters integer value in character array

Tags: c++

So my question is if I have a character array, I'm only allowed to enter characters in it. If I enter integer with character let's suppose "abc123" then this shouldn't be allowed. How to do I do this?

Comment: Iterate over the string and use `std::isdigit` from `<cctype>` to check for digits?

Comment: @GregKikola worth writing that one up as an answer.

Comment: What have you tried so far you need to update it post .Go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [std::none_of](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of), along with `isdigit`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::string test = "abc123";
   if ( std::none_of(test.begin(), test.end(), ::isdigit))
      std::cout << "All good\n"; 
   else
      std::cout << "You've entered an integer\n";

   // Try with good data
   test = "abcdef";
   if ( std::none_of(test.begin(), test.end(), ::isdigit))
      std::cout << "All good\n"; 
   else
      std::cout << "You've entered an integer\n";    
}
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/DvKdeB)